# Не загружаются зависимости в библиотечном модуле

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, зависимости, retrofit2

Я пишу библиотеку. В библиотеке есть зависимости, к примеру `retrofit2`

Зависимость описана в файле `build.gradle (Module: app)`. Я загружаю библиотеку на репозиторий, когда подключаю свою библиотеку в проект, ничего не работает. Но когда я подключу в проект зависимость `retrofit2` все работает.

Теперь получается что у меня две зависимости: одна в библиотеке, вторая в самом проекте. Я хочу чтобы библиотека сама затягивала зависимость `retrofit2` в проект, и мне не нужно было её подключать самому. Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Если либа у вас в виде `aar` файла - то да, она в зависимости, насколько я знаю, не умеет. Как вариант - ппробуйте `jar` файлом её сделать

Comment: jar мне не подходит. Я могу закинуть jar в свою arr?

Comment: На счёт jar не знаю, но может сработать добавление зависимостей в виде проектов, подключенных к либе

Comment: Работает. Спасибо)